# "Slider" type label as seen on Facebook and AP Mobile News

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Please pardon my lack of Photoshop skills, but I'm curious what type of strategy Apps like Facebook and AP Mobile News are using for the 'label slider' in their applications. Here's a quick snippet outlining what I'm talking about as I'm sure the name I'm labeling the utility as is being butchered: http://dl-client.getdropbox.com/u/57676/slider.jpg

Essentially the user can touch the label and glide it along the X axis. It has a smooth bounce effect also once it hits the edges. This gives quite a bit more real estate if you need to present more on the screen than what your portrait mode allows for and is thus very valuable.

Is it a matter of just creating a UILabel that's wider than the screen with a bit of Touch API + Core Animation? Would love insight on how to start tackling this thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll most likely want to use a UIScrollView, with a UILabel as its content view. Size the label appropriately to your content, and then set the contentSize property of the scrollview to that size.

Answer (score 4):

I created a similar control, and it's much easier than you think. It's just a UIScrollView with a series of UIButtons added to it. You could use labels instead of buttons - just depends on the feel you want. I think Facebook is probably using labels for theirs.

In any case, you'll probably want to use a series of components rather than one component (which is what Ben suggested) in the event that you want to, say, style the "selected" label differently from the others. It also makes hit detection a little easier.

You get the bounce effect for free by default - you may have noticed that most scroll views in iPhone apps do the same thing. It can be turned off as well.